# Get the JSON response instead of text/html

Tags: java, rest, apache-httpclient-4.x

**authenticate_user method intended to create it to get the list of projects through the REST API in java:**

```
 @GET
        @Path("/projects")
        @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
        public boolean authenticate_user(String username, String password)
        {
            boolean status = false;
            boolean isUser = isUserExists(username, password);

            if (isUser)
            {
                HttpResponse response = clientConfig(username, password, "projects");
                System.out.println("ProjectResponse >>>" + response);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String content=null;
                try
                {
                    content = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                }
                catch (ParseException | IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("ResponseContent><><><"+content);
                System.out.println("ContentMimeType: "+EntityUtils.getContentMimeType(entity));

                if (response != null)
                {
                    JSONArray getArray =new JSONArray();//Projects
                    status=true;
                System.out.println("SuccessFully login");

            }else

        {
            // TODO user is not validated
            System.out.println("Error: Not Authenticated");
            status = false;
        }
            }   return status;

        }
```

**ClientConfiguration class:**

```
public HttpResponse clientConfig(String username, String password, String prms)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
            HttpClientContext httpContext = HttpClientContext.create();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://" + _HOST + "/" + prms);
            List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Type", "Basic Auth"));
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Username", username));
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", password));
            httpget.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));
            // Execute and get the response.
            httpget.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget, httpContext);

            response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200)
            {
                throw new IOException("Non-successful HTTP response: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() + ":"
                        + response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
            }
            else if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200)
            {
                System.out.println("Response>>>" + response);
                System.out.println("HTTPResponse: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() + ":"
                        + response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
                flag = true;
                return response;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Status is not 200");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

**And my output is html response instead of html response I need the JSON format, Its return me login page**

```
HTTPResponse: 200:OK
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
................  </html>

ContentMimeType: text/html
SuccessFully login
```

**Any one help me to find out the problem.**

Comment: Are you using Jersey on the server side (it looks that way)? If so, then you'll need to create a wrapper around your return boolean value (i.e. a simple class that contains/wraps this boolean value)

Comment: ok, but I used HTTPRequest and Response.

Comment: Yes, I can see that you're using Apache HTTP client but I was asking about the server framework.

Comment: Yes, server supported jersey. so, I need to change way of implementation??.

Answer (score -1):

Try like this:

```
String json_string = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(json_string);
```

Comment: No, this can't be handled on the client side.

Answer (score -1):

**Thank you, Friends, Now I solved this issue with Jersey framework. And here is a solution of it.**

```
 String url = "http://support.sigmastream.com/issues.json";
        String output = "";
        String authString = username + ":" + password;
        String authStringEnc = new BASE64Encoder().encode(authString.getBytes());
        try
        {
            Client restClient = Client.create();
            WebResource webResource = restClient.resource(url);
            ClientResponse resp = webResource.accept("application/json")
                    .header("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc).get(ClientResponse.class);
            if (resp.getStatus() != 200)
            {
                throw new IOException(
                        "Non-successful HTTP response: " + resp.getStatus() + " : " + resp.getStatusInfo());
            }
            else
            {
                output = resp.getEntity(String.class);
                System.out.println("response: " + output);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ie)
        {
            System.out.println(ie.getMessage());
        }
```